# Why am I not able to authorise myself when I pass my token through the URL, but when I put it in the headers in the key/value section, it works?

Tags: post, request, azure-functions, postman, key-value

Here is an example of how I passed my value through the URL; If I correctly remember, to pass any key/value in the URL, I just need to use the "?" after the URL and add my "key" and "value".

[image]

The error I get is a "401 unauthorized".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For query parameter, your should use `code` as shown below

```
https://<APP_NAME>.azurewebsites.net/api/<FUNCTION_NAME>?code=<API_KEY>
```

If by Http header then use `x-functions-key`.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#api-key-authorization)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks for the link to the documentation.